# This is the CSS i have written, trying to center the content as shown in the photo

Tags: html, css

This is the HTML code
If there is a better way to write it please tell me.

Now of to the CSS, I am trying to center the content and make it look like the picture, but Whenever I use Display Flex in body tag, it works but it centers the whole content and messes up the current alignment of text content, is there any way so that I can center the image with the text content and then center it all with respect to the main browser page.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lexend+Deca&display=swap");

body {
  background-color: hsl(233, 47%, 7%);
  font-size: 15px;
}

#main-heading {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
}

#insights {
  color: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
}

#para {
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
  background-blend-mode: hard-light;
  font-family: "Lexend Deca", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#stats {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
#companies {
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

#templates,
#queries {
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

#que,
#temp,
#comp {
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
  font-family: "Lexend Deca", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
}
#image {
  background-blend-mode: ;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="firstproject.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
<body>
    <h1 id="main-heading">Get <span id="insights">insights</span> that help<br>
    your business grow.  </h1>
    <p id="para">Discorver the benefits of data analytics and make<br>
    better decisions regarding revenue, customer<br>
    experience, and overall efficiency.</p>
<div id="stats">
    <div id="companies"><span>10k+</span><br><span id="comp">companies</span></div>
    <div id="templates"><span>314</span><br><span id="temp">templates</span></div>
    <div id="queries"><span>12M+</span><br><span id="que">queries</span></div>
</div>

<div id="image">
    <img id="main-image" src="image-header-desktop.jpg" alt="main_image.jpg">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how mine looks like:

[image]

This is how it should look like:

[image]

Comment: The code snippet isn't very useful without a working jpeg. Perhaps you can add a fiddle or a link to your work so people can try it with the web debugger.

Comment: @Alucard take a look at tailwindcss. It's a framework which is really useful for things like that

Answer (score 1):

Set both your `body` and `html` to have a 100% `height`, then use flex and set `justify-content` and `align-items` on the `body` to `center`.

Then make a container and put your text and image content inside it, with its `flex-direction` set to `row`.

When you get down to your mobile breakpoint you can set the `flex-direction` in your container to `column` if you want to stack your elements:

```css
        @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&display=swap");
        @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lexend+Deca&display=swap");

        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {
            background-color: hsl(233, 47%, 7%);
            font-size: 15px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            max-width:700px;
        }

        #main-heading {
            color: white;
            font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
        }

        #insights {
            color: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
        }

        #para {
            color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
            background-blend-mode: hard-light;
            font-family: "Lexend Deca", sans-serif;
            font-weight: 400;
        }

        #stats {
            font-size: 15px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-start;
        }

        #companies {
            color: white;
            text-align: left;
            margin-top: 50px;
            font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: bolder;
        }

        #templates,
        #queries {
            color: white;
            text-align: left;
            margin-left: 50px;
            margin-top: 50px;
            font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: bolder;
        }

        #que,
        #temp,
        #comp {
            color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
            font-family: "Lexend Deca", sans-serif;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: 500;
        }

        #image {
           width:400px;
           height:300px;
        }

        #image img {
            width:100%;
           height:100%;
           object-fit:cover;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href="firstproject.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&display=swap");
        @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lexend+Deca&display=swap");

        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {
            background-color: hsl(233, 47%, 7%);
            font-size: 15px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            max-width:700px;
        }

        #main-heading {
            color: white;
            font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
        }

        #insights {
            color: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
        }

        #para {
            color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
            background-blend-mode: hard-light;
            font-family: "Lexend Deca", sans-serif;
            font-weight: 400;
        }

        #stats {
            font-size: 15px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-start;
        }

        #companies {
            color: white;
            text-align: left;
            margin-top: 50px;
            font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: bolder;
        }

        #templates,
        #queries {
            color: white;
            text-align: left;
            margin-left: 50px;
            margin-top: 50px;
            font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: bolder;
        }

        #que,
        #temp,
        #comp {
            color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
            font-family: "Lexend Deca", sans-serif;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: 500;
        }

        #image {
           width:400px;
           height:300px;
        }

        #image img {
            width:100%;
           height:100%;
           object-fit:cover;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="text-container">
            <h1 id="main-heading">Get <span id="insights">insights</span> that help<br> your business grow. </h1>
            <p id="para">Discorver the benefits of data analytics and make<br> better decisions regarding revenue,
                customer<br> experience, and overall efficiency.</p>
            <div id="stats">
                <div id="companies"><span>10k+</span><br><span id="comp">companies</span></div>
                <div id="templates"><span>314</span><br><span id="temp">templates</span></div>
                <div id="queries"><span>12M+</span><br><span id="que">queries</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="image-container">
            <div id="image">
                <img id="main-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501059520966-c59141726d6c?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8YmxhY2slMjBhbmQlMjB3aGl0ZSUyMGZsb3dlcnxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="main_image.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```